# How to get better performance for a Get One Entity with multiple relations

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, doctrine, api-platform.com

I've got an API Resource based on a "house" entity. Each house can have several rooms, several car parks, several photos, several diagnoses, several documents, ...

By default, since API PLATFORM force eager loading, the framework execute a single query with appropriate left-join statements. In my case, I sometimes have over 100,000 results for a single "house" (the model is more complex than described).

As there are too many results, I get a timeout...

One way to get better performance is to disable force eager for that API Resource. To get all data, the framework execute about twenty queries but the query time is only around twenty ms.

Is it a good way ? What are the disadvantages of this method ? Do you see possible side effects ?

Comment: Do you mean each of your house child entity are serialized with the house entity while calling it ? And why your relation are in eager loading by default ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: U Need to work with Groups to only load this data u Really Need.